# How can i find out different languages in pandas dataframe other than english

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, google-translate

I have a pandas dataframe. The TEXT column contains mix of different languages. The data volume is huge (more than 40k records) and hence I'm getting time out exception while applying google translator. Hence I'm trying to identify languages other than english and then apply translator only those rows.

For your reference I've created below sample dataframe, and apply language detect.

```
import pandas as pd

mydata = {'ID': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        'TEXT': ['How are you', '你好吗 hope all good', '元気ですか', 'cómo estás' , 'Hope all good 元気ですか']}

df = pd.DataFrame(mydata)
df['Language'] = df['TEXT'].apply(detect)
print(df)
```

My output looks like :

[image]

where I'm expecting the Language column of ID #2 should contains "cn" and ID #5 contains "ja".
Any other language combining with english is appearing as "en".

Comment: Do you know what languages are in the data? If you can make certain assumptions, like "all rows are `en` unless all the characters in a row are Japanese or a Latin letter has a diacritical marking", you might get pretty close. Or you could at least narrow down which rows you need Google to disambiguate.

Comment: The actual data i'm extracting can have any language. So it will be difficult to apply the logic. Is there any other way to find out if there is any language other than en? The 'TEXT' column may have mix of different languages.